# User.findOne() in a collection other than 'Users'

Tags: java, node.js, mongoose

I wrote an app that has a logic for email verification and it's trigered when an user sign up. I use two Mongoose models: one to record the data from the users and other model for the authentication tokens. In the token schema I grab the user's ID.

[image]

In my User controller, when the app needs to authenticate the token that was prevously sent to the user, the token is identified and after that I must to find the user's ID that was recorded in the token schema in it's Mongo collection. For that, I have a `User.findOne()` function.

What I'm wanna do is to grab the _userId:ObjectId("some-userid-number") that is stored in the token collection, but I must to doi te inside the fuction, something like that

```
User.findOne({ _userID: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId._userID, ref: 'Token' })
```

So, how can I grab the _userId stored as a ObjectId in the Token model?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: To sum it up. The token value is presented by the user, and the query needs to figure out which userId the token belongs to?

Comment: Yes, @jorgenkg... That's it ...

Answer (score 1):

If the Mongoose models are defined with [refs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#saving-refs), findOne/findAll can join data from multiple collections using populate. Note that using populate will result in multiple queries being sent to mongodb.

```js
Token
  .findOne({ token })
  .select("_userId")
  .populate({
    path: '_userId',
    select: 'firstName', // Specify the necessary user properties
    options: { lean: true }
  })
  .lean()
  .exec();
```

The request can instead be formulated as an [aggregation query](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate) if performance is important. This request will result in a single query being sent to mongodb.

```js
Token
  .aggregate([
    {$match: {
        token
    }},
    {$lookup: {
        from: 'users', // the name of the user collection
        localField: '_userId',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'user'
    }},
    {$project: {
        // Specify the necessary user properties in the projection
        firstName: '$user.firstName'
    }}
  ])
  .exec()
```

Remember to create an index on `Token(_userId)`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @jorgenk. But I must confess that I didn't understand how to implement it in my code. There is no single line solution to put it into User.findOne() function?

Comment: I think that my question suffered from poor details about all my code. Sorry for that and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple than I imagine :-)

```
async confirmationPost (req, res) {
    const token_ = req.body.token;
    await Token.findOne({ token:token_ }, function (err, tokenData) {
       if (!tokenData) {
          return res.status(),
       }
       else 
       {     
       tokenUser = tokenData._userId
       User.findOne({ _id: tokenUser }, function (err, user) {
       // logic-logic
       }
```

I was able to captura all the token colletion data, so was a simpla case of defining tha variable :-)